# Generating consecutive numbered urls

Tags: unix, url, text-files, generate, numbered

I want to generate a text file containing the folowing lines:

```
http://example.com/file1.pdf
http://example.com/file2.pdf
http://example.com/file3.pdf
.
.
http://example.com/file1000.pdf
```

Can any one advise how to do it using unix command line, please?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps you can suggest some solution and tell us what specifically doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an interating for loop

```
for (( i=1;i<=1000;i++ ));
do 
    echo "http://example.com/file$i.pdf";
done > newfile
```

With seq:

```
while read i;
do 
   echo "http://example.com/file$i.pdf";
done <<< $(seq 1000) > newfile
```

Comment: Thank you all!

On my Mac I use this:

```print -l 'http://example.com/file'{1..1000}.pdf > newfile```

On my Unix machine, I use this (by Raman Sailopal), this works on Mac as well:

```for (( i=1;i<=1000;i++ )); do echo "http://example.com/file$i.pdf"; done > newfile;```

Comment: Great. If the suggestion meets your requirement, could you kindly up vote and accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create/run a python script file ato generate this. Using vim, nano, or any other terminal editor, create a python file as follows:

```
def genFile(fn, start, end):
  with open(fn, "w+") as f:
    f.writelines([f"http://example.com/file{str(i)}.pdf\n" for i in range(start, end+1)])

try:
  fn = input("File Path: ") # can be relative
  start = int(input("Start: ")) # inclusive
  end = int(input("End: ")) # inclusive
  genFile(fn, start, end)
except:
  print("Invalid Input")
```

Once this is written to a file, let's call it script.py. We can run the following command to execute the script:

```
python script.py
```

Then, fill out the prompts for the file path, start, and end. This should result in all those lines printed in the file specified delimited by '\n'.